# Ward identity in scalar QED; gauge transformations & plane wave solutions for polarization

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, ward-identity

I am prepping for my QFT2 exam tomorrow, and in one of the mock exams I found the following question (and I'm not quite sure how to go about this). Given the following Lagrangian:

$$
L = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} - (D_{\mu}\phi*)D^{\mu}\phi - m^2\phi\phi*
$$

where

$$F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}$$
and $D$ the covariant derivative:

$$D_{\mu}\phi = (\partial_{\mu} - ieA_{\mu})\phi $$
The question being asked is the following: Consider a plane-wave solution to the vacuum Maxwell equations of motion with a transverse polarization vector $\epsilon_{\mu}^{(\lambda)}(p)$:

$$A_{\mu}(x) = \epsilon_{\mu}^{(\lambda)}(p)e^{ipx}$$

Show that you can obtain another plane-wave solution with a polarization vector:

$$\epsilon_{\mu}^{(\lambda)}(p) + f(p)p_{\mu}$$

by performing a gauge transformation $A_{\mu}(x) \rightarrow A_{\mu}(x) + \partial_{\mu}\alpha(x)$ with a suitably chosen $\alpha(x)$.

I started by plugging in the given polarization vector in terms of A in the equation of motion to see if this indeed results in a solution, which indeed it does. However, I am not quite sure on how to proceed. Do I try and plug in the new plane wave solution into the equation of motion and see if this is also a solution? Or do I just show that the Lagrangian is gauge invariant and that the $f(p)p$ term has to coincide with the partial alpha term? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to show that $\alpha = f(p)e^{ipx}$ generates the proposed ansatz (which you have verified is also a solution to the vacuum equation).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I'm quite understanding, do you mean that $\alpha = f(p)p_{\mu}$ generates the proposed ansatz?

Comment: You already have $A_{\mu} = \epsilon_{\mu}(p)e^{ipx}$. Choose $\alpha = -if(p)e^{ipx}$. This means the gauge transformed field is $A_{\mu} =  \epsilon_{\mu}(p)e^{ipx} + \partial_{\mu}(-if(p)e^{ipx}) = ( \epsilon_{\mu}(p) +f(p)p_{\mu})e^{ipx}$ which is the new solution that has been proposed.